# Curious about peculiar JavaScript issue regarding script tag type attribute

Tags: javascript, html

So, my team is using the HTML5 Boilerplate and has the site nearly finished.  I want to do a quick JavaScript test to make sure the client can add their own JavaScript if they so desire.  I know the type attribute for the script tag is not required when using the HTML5 doctype, but the JavaScript alert doesn't even work when it's used (which is what has me confused as I've built HTML5 sites while using the type attribute in the script tag.

What works:

```
    <script>        
      alert("HELP");        
    </script>
```

What doesn't work:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">     
      alert("HELP");        
    </script>
```

Can anyone explain what's going on?  This DOES work for other HTML5 based websites...

***Tested with Firefox 12 on Ubuntu 12.04

Thanks guys.

P.S.  It's not going to make or break the site, is not very important, etc. I was just wondering why this problem exists.

***EDIT***

Here's a link to a publically hosted page that WORKS.

http://illinois.edu/1500/index.html

Why does it not work on my local box (shakes head)...?

Comment: Gonna be kind of difficult to answer unless you can provide a code sample that shows the issue. I am unable to reproduce in FF12/OSX.

Comment: I created a new html document with the html5 doctype and both of the above scripts worked for me in Firefox 12 and Chrome. I'm sure you already have, but quadruple check your spelling of words like script, type, text, and javascript. Sorry, but good luck.

Comment: if its a local problem, check to see if the html source is different. you might have an antivirus/security software or something similar stripping/modify the html. barring that, inspect the dom programatically, because maybe a browser addon is modifying it the dom, which wouldnt be detectable via looking at the html source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both versions are correct and should work. Either there's a problem in your code like a missing  tag or more likely you've checked the "Prevent this page from creating aditional dialogs" checkbox.

Replace your alerts with this and try it out in Chrome:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
console.log('HELP');
</script>
<script>
console.log('HELP');
</script>
```

Now run the page in Chrome, press F12 go to Console and see if the messages pop up

Comment: +1. It's important to know about the implications of the "Prevent this page from creating aditional dialogs" checkbox. You simply can't rely on any `alert()` message you produce ever being seen by the user.